# Are website review links toxic such that they should be disavowed?

Tags: seo, google, backlinks, disavow-links

You know, there are tons of sites on the internet which check the value of sites, showing traffic details about sites, seo score checker sites, whois checker sites etc..

Also, some of them are 4-5-6 PR; big sites, for example:

```
www.websitestatz.com/info/example.com
www.websitevalues.net/example.com.html
```

Are these links are toxic or not? Should we write them to our disavow file?

Or how can I check if a URL is toxic or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. These and others are not toxic sites. Google knows these kinds of sites very well and discount their links to your site. Often, these links will add a small value to your overall profile, but are considered very low quality none-the-less.

Be careful not to disavow links unless you know that they are toxic. It is a bad practice to disavow links as a rule. Only disavow links as a last resort and only if the links are causing damage to your PR in a significant way.

Comment: but the link delete services add these siteinfo links to disavow file.. they are also clean small directory listing sites as like submityoursite.com etc..

Comment: I don't know what these "link delete services" are but they sound like snake oil to me.

Comment: @deniz DisgruntledGoat is right. There are plenty of people making money on your fear. SEO especially. Don't buy the bull. If these sites in your Q are the least of your worries, then you have no worries. I've got a cr@p10@d of these sites linking to me and it is not dragging me down at all. Google knows who the leaches are.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat snake oil is too kind. There are legit uses for these services for sure, however, they are trading in fear. Most of what they do is horse pucky.

Comment: haha :) thank you all; i understand.. (DisgruntledGoat: as like services: linkresearchtools.com, linkdelete.com etc)